# Keep-Alive http header with timeout not used by google, stackoverflow, etc?

Tags: http

I started reading about Keep-Alive and was thinking about adding it to my webserver but as I traced http://google.com and http://stackoverflow.com, I noticed they are not sending this header at all back to the clients (with a timeout that is).

Why is that?  I would think normally you want to kill connections that have been idle for more than 20 seconds or so.  I was actually curious what other websites were using.  Perhaps they do timeout the idle connection eventually but just don't tell the clients they are going to do that(which seems odd).

I did a "telnet google.com 80" and waited about 2 minutes and it never timed out and then I issued a "GET / HTTP/1.1" and waited some more than typed in a bunch of random garbage over and over(not sure they limit the header size either so you 'could' OOM their servers I think).  I finally hit enter twice and got back a 200 OK....none of my headers were well-formed but google didn't seem to care(odd).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 3):

In HTTP/1.1 and above keep-alive is the default unless the server explicitly sends a "Close" message: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3 so there is no need to send a `Connection: keep-alive` header.

And in fact under HTTP/2 you're not even allowed to send this Close header so there's no way NOT to use keep-alives except to explicitly close the connection after a request is processed [with a GOAWAY message][1].

Under HTTP/1.1 servers can close the connection without telling the client.

So Google and StackExchange are using keep-alives - they are just not advertising it in the headers.

Comment: I was asking more about the timeout feature of the keep alive than the keep alive itself.  It seems google is not using the timeout.  In fact, I just did a telnet into google.com port 80 and it seems to just let me do that forever.....isn't that a bad thing as you could DOS on too many open connections.  It seems strange they don't time it out.

Comment: Yeah since HTTP/1.1 there is no explicit timeout given back in header however there will be a timeout on the server. Try leaving telnet session on and you'll see it eventually is closed. Not providing a time (which was never guaranteed anyway) allows other options to be handled by server (e.g. Max Requests made on that connection, max connections from clients...etc.).

Comment: you must have missed my edit?  google and stackoverflow never closed my connection and left it open.  On top of that, chrome connects without sending any requests at all sometimes(I think to be ready for more or something) as I ended up implementing a timeout feature but am now thinking of ripping it back out since chrome connects with no requests coming in sometimes.